# Function constructor initialization in JS?

Tags: javascript

How should I initialize `Function constructor` function :

(both seems to work.)

like this :

```
var t= new Function ("a","alert(a)");
t(3)//3
alert(Object.prototype.toString.apply(t)); //[object Function]
```

or

```
var t= Function ("a","alert(a)"); //without new 
t(3) //3
alert(Object.prototype.toString.apply(t));//[object Function]
```

Is there any difference ?

[*jsbin*](http://jsbin.com/upazac/2/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are identical. From [the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.1):

> When `Function` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new Function object. Thus the function call `Function(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression new `Function(…)` with the same arguments.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for not finding it myself.(searched though)

Answer (score 1):

> Both are same.

But if you use new, every property inside the object will have a new instance.